# How can I check if the hit rate of the correct answer significantly differed between groups?

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data, post-hoc, percentage

I have a task in my experiment, where participants had to select an emotion out of 7 options dependent on a video they saw. The participants were split between three groups. Now I want to check, if there is a significant difference in hit rate between the groups and I am not sure how to do this.
I transformed the data the participants submitted to a binomial variable: They either had the correct response or not.
On that data I tried out binomial logistic regression, but I realized that might not be what I am looking for, since the logistic pretty much finds out all groups have a probability of hitting the correct emotion, so there is no significant difference. So how can I do it? For example, for the surprised emotion, the hit rates between the groups were: 95%, 73,7% and 70% with group samples of 20 persons in first and third and 19 persons in the second condition.

EDIT: In a perfect world, I would be able to even check the difference between groups over all three hit rates. But I guess this might lead to issues, since there is only one hit rate per emotion, so we don't have anything like a distribution.

EDIT2: I found that apparently there is something with the Chi-Squared-test that gives me information. I tried the test for surprised with all three groups and it reported non-significance (since the difference between group 2 + 3 is highly insignificant). But when I exclude group 2 it reports significance for the other two. So I basically want to do something like an ANOVA, but for the hit rates, telling me if there is some difference between any groups and being able to do post-hoc tests for the different groups.

Example data:

| Quota | Emotion Correct? |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 | Yes |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | No |
| 3 | Yes |
| 1 | No |
| 2 | Yes |

Comment: You want to test, for each emotion separately, if the hit rate (aka recall aka sensitivity) is the same for all three groups or not?

Comment: @dipetkov Almost. I want to test for each emotion (and if possible also for all three emotions at once) if either of the faces significantly differ from each other. For example, I want to know if surprised has significantly lower recall for face 3, but also (if possible) test if the recall over all emotions is significantly lower for face 3. (But I can imagine the second thing is statistically not possible, except I create a kind of averaging variable.) So not all groups need to have differences from each other, I also want to know when, for example 1 +3 differ, but 2+3 are almost the same.

Comment: You have seven options, and three groups, so how did you apply binomial logistic regression? which is for two possible responses ... please add details, maybe share your data?  (or some mock-up data of the same structure)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sorry, edited: Of course I transformed the data from 7 options to a "Correct/Incorrect" bool for the binomial regression. So the data is dichotomous.

Comment: How would you do it if the outcome were continuous (say Gaussian) and you wanted to test if those Gaussian outcomes had different means for each of your three groups?

Comment: @Dave With an ANOVA. But I can't use an ANOVA for dichotomous data. And Chi-Squared-test doesn't return if either of the groups differ significantly, but only if all of them differ significantly. At least that's what I suppose, since it gives me a p-value of 0,107 with all three groups, but one of 0,037 with only the two that differ. Could be due to a p-value correction, but that would seem a bit too strongly corrected to me.

Comment: If you did an ANOVA for a continuous outcome, how would you assess which groups differ significantly?

Comment: With a post-hoc test. But I don't know what would be such a post-hoc test for dichotomous data.